# Trying to print every nth element in strange data format that is identified as list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pulling data via an API that python identifies as a list, but does not seem to act like one.

This is a sample of the data returned:

```
[{'product_id': '41111', 'type': 'configurable', 'set': '4', 'sku': 'CM5555-CONF', 'position': '1'}, {'product_id': '42222', 'type': 'configurable', 'set': '4', 'sku': 'CM6666-CONF', 'position': '1'}
```

This is in a varaiable called temp.

When I do print(type(temp)), `<class 'list'>` is returned.

I am trying to access a list of all product IDs, so they can be fed to a different request to the API.

When I do `print(temp[::1])`, the entire list (or whatever it is) is returned, as though I just did `print(temp)` by itself.

How can I print just a list of product_ids by themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it is a list but inside the list are {} which are dictionaries. You have to reference their key in order to pull them out. Try:

```
for datadict in temp:
    print(datadict['product_id'])
```